# "update" query - error invalid input synatx for integer: "{39}" - postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

I'm using node js 0.10.12 to perform querys to postgreSQL 9.1.

I get the error `error invalid input synatx for integer: "{39}"` (39 is an example number) when I try to perform an `update` query

I cannot see what is going wrong. Any advise?

Here is my code (snippets) in the front-end

```
    //this is global
    var gid=0;

    //set websockets to search - works fine
    var sd = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:0000");

    sd.onmessage = function (evt) 
    { 
    //get data, parse it, because there is more than one vars, pass id to gid
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    var packet = JSON.parse(received_msg);
    var tid = packet['tid'];
    gid=tid;
    }

    //when user clicks button, set websockets to send id and other data, to perform update query
    var sa = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:0000");

    sa.onopen = function(){
     sa.send(JSON.stringify({
      command:'typesave', 
      indi:gid, 
      name:document.getElementById("typename").value, 
    }));

sa.onmessage = function (evt) { 
alert("Saved");
sa.close;
gid=0;//make gid 0 again, for re-use
}
```

And the back -end (query)

```
var query=client.query("UPDATE type SET t_name=$1,t_color=$2 WHERE t_id = $3 ",[name, color, indi])
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
        });
        query.on("end", function (result) {
    connection.send("o");
    client.end();
});
```

Why this not work and the number does not get recognized?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `indi` when you call `client.query`?

Comment: @muistooshort Is just a var, has the same name like in the fornt-end. Check the `sa.send(JSON.stringify({` in the front-end code. Contanis the id that the query is based at. I replace the whole code with `connection.send(indi);` and then alert it on the front end. Is `39`

Comment: But what is its value when you call `client.query`?

Comment: @muistooshort Hmmm...I dont know how to check this...Sorry. Any suggestions?

Comment: @muistooshort Hello again. Rigth before I call the query, the value is `[ 39 ]`. At least , this is what the console says. Before I call the `client.query` I print the value. And it says `[ 39 ]`. Is this right? In the front-end I check the value in Firebug, nothing weird...Any help? Thanks

Comment: `[39]` looks like an array to me and `{39}` is (sort of) an array literal in PostgreSQL so I'd guess that `indi` is an array when you call `client.query`, maybe try passing `[name, color, indi[0]]` to `client.query`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the anser. I simply did `indi:gid.toString()` in the `JSON.stringify` and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As one would expect from the initial problem, your database driver is sending in an integer array of one member into a field for an integer.  PostgreSQL rightly rejects the data and return an error. `'{39}'` in PostgreSQL terms is exactly equivalent to `ARRAY[39]` using an array constructor and `[39]` in JSON.

Now, obviously you can just change your query call to pull the first item out of the JSON array. and send that instead of the whole array, but I would be worried about what happens if things change and you get multiple values.  You may want to look at separating that logic out for this data structure.